# Alternatives to Xcode Storyboard XIB NIB interface builder?

Tags: macos, xcode, ios

Maybe it is just me because I am a programmer, but I find Xcodes interface builder for creating xib/nib/storyboards to be extremely difficult to use and not intuitive at all. I would much rather play around with coding a UI than trying to decrypt interface builder.

Are there any alternatives out there, like some kind of wysiwyg drag and drop editor where I can create my own UI and then have it exported to Objective-C/Swift code that I can just drop into Xcode?

Comment: if you don't mind using Webapplication give Cappuccino a try http://www.cappuccino-project.org

Comment: or if you like to create Native OS X Applications have a look at this http://www.guilmo.com/how-to-create-an-onoff-uiswitch-programmatically/ it is possible to add all the UI Elements also programmatically although but you still need to know how storyboards/xibs work (cause your just progrmming what you othereise would have vlicked together) - you still need to know how to connect your actions/outlets and your code

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at MarkupKit:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

It's an open-source framework I wrote that allows you to build native iOS apps in markup, similar to XAML or Android development. For example, you can create a label instance like this:

```
<UILabel text="Hello, World" font="System 24" textColor="#ff0000/>
```

rather than this:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];

[label setText:@"Hello, World"];
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Obviously, that's a simple example - the value of using markup becomes much more apparent with more complex view hierarchies. It also supports dynamic localization and CSS-like styling.

You can find articles and examples on my blog:

https://gkbrown.wordpress.com

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I created MarkupKit specifically to address the use case outlined by the original poster: "...I find Xcodes interface builder for creating xib/nib/storyboards to be extremely difficult to use...I would much rather play around with coding a UI than trying to decrypt interface builder". So it seems on-topic, and I'm not selling anything (the project is open-source).